# Can not see data on VisualForce page for Big Objects data

Tags: apex, visualforce, data, big-object

I created a Visual force page for Big object data to be seen. However when i import data from workbench i am unable to see the full data in VF page. For some reason i can only 2 records out of 10 and those 2 record are first and last record in the table. I can not figure out what is the problem that the full data wouldn't be visible in VF table. please advise me what can be the solution to this issue. i am very new to the salesforce and doesnt know much about VF and Apex codes.

Visualforce Codes:

```
<apex:page controller="EmailArchive" title="Email Archive">
<apex:sectionHeader title="EmailArchive" subtitle="All Archived Email"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listOfEmailArchive}" var="email">
        <apex:column value="{!email.ID__c}"/>  
        <apex:column value="{!email.Parent_ID__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!email.Message_Date__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!email.Subject__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!email.Text_Body__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!email.HTML_Body__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!email.FROM_ADDRESS__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!email.TO_ADDRESS__c}"/>    
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Apex class:

```
public class EmailArchive{
public List<Email_Archive__b> listOfEmailArchive {get;set;}
public EmailArchive(){
    listOfEmailArchive = [SELECT Subject__c, ID__c, CREATED_DATE__c, FROM_ADDRESS__c, Headers__c, TO_ADDRESS__C, Last_modified_DATE__c, System_MOD_Stamp__c, Text_Body__c, HTML_Body__c, From_Name__c, Validated_From_Address__c, CC_Address__c, BCC_Address__c, Incoming__c, Has_Attachment__c, Status__c, Message_Date__c, Is_Deleted__c, Is_Externally_Visible__c, Message_Identifier__c, Reply_to_Email_Message_ID__c, Thread_Identifier__c, Is_Cliet_Managed__c, Related_to_ID__c, Last_modified_by__c, Parent_ID__c, Created_by_ID__c FROM Email_Archive__b];
    if(listOfEmailArchive == null){
        listOfEmailArchive = new List<Email_Archive__b>();
    }
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Exs.jpg)

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have inserted all the screenshots that might be needed to find the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant sections of your Visualforce code and Apex controller into your question, and use the `{}` tool or Ctrl-K to format them so we can read them. Your screenshots do not show enough code and are not easy for users to read.

Comment: HI david, Thanks for your reply. I have just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an authoritative answer here, but I have an idea as to what may be the issue.

BigObjects are intended to hold millions of records or more. The [SOQL that is supported by BigObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/big_object_querying.htm#!) is intentionally very limited, and the design intent is that you should be writing a query against the fields you defined as part of the BigObject's index when you created it:

> You can query the fields in a big object’s index using a subset of standard SOQL commands.
>
> Build an index query starting from the first field defined in the index, without gaps between the first and last field in the query. You can use =, <, >, <=, or >=, or IN on the last field in your query. Any prior fields in your query can only use the = operator. The !=, LIKE, NOT IN, EXCLUDES, and INCLUDES operators are not valid in any query.

While I can't locate a reference that states that BigObjects cannot be queried without a filter in regular SOQL (as opposed to Async SOQL), I'm speculating that this unusual behavior you've observed is a species of undefined behavior stemming from running an unfiltered SOQL query against a BigObject.

Since you certainly cannot expect such a query to work in production, when your BigObject's data is populated at scale, I would recommend rewriting the query against the BigObject's index fields to see whether the result is as expected in this situation.

Comment: Thanks david I had figured it out it was due to the chosen Index fields in schema. I couldnt tell the reason behind it but when i recreated Big Object with different Indexed field I was able to see the data. Thank you